# Determine if a server is asking for a client certificate using openssl s_client

Tags: openssl

I am using `openssl` to connect to servers to detect if they require a client certificate.

Currently I am using this command:

```
openssl s_client -connect pokyloky.com:5222 -state 2>&1 | grep 'server certificate request' 

SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate request A
```

I am surprised that simply using:

```
openssl s_client -connect pokyloky.com:5222
```

doesn't indicate directly that a client certificate has been requested. There is a handshake error:

```
139843101763232:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1262:SSL alert number 40
139843101763232:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
```

But it doesn't explicitly state why the handshake has failed.

Why does `openssl s_connect` not indicate clearly that the server requested a certificate and the handshake has failed because of this?

Comment: The server may send alert 40 (handshake failed) because it requested a client cert and didn't receive one, but it may do so for many other reasons, and many servers request a client cert but do continue and do not fail when the client chooses not to provide one, so `s_client` can't know for sure which reason or combination of reasons the server had.

Answer (score 4):

## That behaviour is not part of TLS v1.2

> But it doesn't explicitly state why the handshake has failed.

It can't. It's not defined as part of the (TLS v1.2) protocol.

When the server or client decides to abort a connection, they can choose from one out of several `alert` messages.

An [`Alert` message looks like this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#page-29):

```
struct {
      AlertLevel level;
      AlertDescription description;
} Alert;
```

`AlertLevel` is one byte wide and only has two states:

```
enum { warning(1), fatal(2), (255) } AlertLevel;
```

And `AlertDescription` is one byte wide as well. But [out of the 256 possible reason codes only about 30 are assigned and used](http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-6). And of these 30, there simply is none, that fits the *"Hey, I told you I wanted a client certificate, why didn't you give me one?!?"*-bill.

(And although it sounds like it might fit, `no_certificate_RESERVED(41)` was used for something else. Namely in SSLv3.0 it was used for the other direction: for the CLIENT to tell the server *"Sorry, I can't give you a client certificate."*)

Now for the deeper question *"Wouldn't it make sense to define such a reason code if there are plenty unused code points left? Instead of just hard, largely unexplained failure?"* my answer is simply: *"I don't know."*

I don't see how having such an alert could make the protocol weaker, but crypto is tricky, and I'm not sure.

### Loadbalancer to give friendly error message

But what if you want to give a friendly error message?

AFAIK, then you must do somewhat complicated things with loadbalancer like logic and just initially allow the clientcert-less connection, but then immediately redirect to an error page. Apache can do such a thing [with a rule similar to this](http://ryandlane.com/blog/2010/07/29/requiring-ssl-client-authentication-in-a-user-friendly-way-in-apache/):

```
RewriteCond %{SSL:SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY} !^SUCCESS$
RewriteRule .* /help/ssl-client-auth-required.html [L]
```

IIS defines a HTTP eror message called [`403.7 Forbidden: Client Certificate Required`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/186812). I think this is a smart move (better than just failing, at least), even though [the `.7` of `403.7` is non-standard](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) and I think the error message belongs on the TLS layer and not the HTTP layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the verbose output of the protocol by adding the flag **-trace**. The [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/s_client.html) states that:

> -trace
>
> ```
> show verbose trace output of protocol messages. OpenSSL needs to be compiled with enable-ssl-trace for this option to work.
> ```

You can, of course, use the flags **-state**, **-debug** and **-msg** to retrieve extensive information on how the selected protocol works as well as the states openssl goes through:

> -state
>
> ```
> prints out the SSL session states.
> ```
>
> -debug
>
> ```
> print extensive debugging information including a hex dump of all traffic.
> ```
>
> -msg
>
> ```
> show all protocol messages with hex dump.
> ```

Comment: Yes the -state option shows that a certificate was requested. But I would expect that, without any options, you would be warned that the handshake failed because a certificate was not provided.

Comment: What is the output when running with -trace set?